# bundling js files with browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, bundling-and-minification

I am working with Angularjs as my front end. i was using grunt as build tool but now i want to switch to npm as my build tool as per below link.

[npm script as build tool](https://medium.com/@housecor/why-i-left-gulp-and-grunt-for-npm-scripts-3d6853dd22b8#.yop2pz28p)

now the actual problem is while bundling JS without Grunt

in Grunt we can have concate task which is quite easy to configure. mention below
 `js: ["src/*.js", "src/**/*.js", "!src/apiG/*.js", "!src/apiG/**/*.js"]`,

right now as per my limited knowledge **Browserify** can be use for bundling all my local javascript.(if anyone can suggest me any other package for bundling my javascript files .. Welcome !!)

With browserify i have tried following in my package.json but it didnt work

```
 "build:bundle": "browserify "src/*.js", "src/**/*.js", "!src/apiG/*.js", "!src/apiG/**/*.js" -o ./dist/js/bundle.js",
```

can anyone suggest me how to bundle nested javascript with all options like ignore and all. in browserfy.

i dnt wanted to use "require()" to include all javascript. just want simple bundling of all the files in my project and ignore vendor files. etc..

also if someone can suggest for minification as well. :) (i am expecting too much here i know :) )

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use bash to find all files, prune the unwanted ones and concatenate the contents:

```
find src -type f -name \*.js | egrep -v 'src/apiG/' | xargs cat >dist/js/bundle.js
```

If you require additional processing, simply pipe it through the appropriate command(s) at the end before writing to bundle.js

```
find src -type f -name \*.js | egrep -v 'src/apiG/' | xargs cat | minify_command >dist/js/bundle.js
```